# Twoside fancyhdr rule

Tags: fancyhdr, double-sided

Fancyhdr allows defining odd and even side headers and footers. But is it possible to use different headrule for odd and even pages?

I use an asymmetric ornament in the `\headrule` and would like it mirrored on every other page.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\headrule}{
\vspace{-8pt}\hrulefill\quad\pgfornament[width=2cm]{14}\quad\hrulefill}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could test if the pagenumber is even or odd:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[strict]{changepage}


\renewcommand{\headrule}{
\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage
  \vspace{-8pt}\hrulefill\quad\pgfornament[width=2cm]{14}\quad\hrulefill
\else
  \vspace{-8pt}\hrulefill\quad\reflectbox{\pgfornament[width=2cm]{14}}\quad\hrulefill
\fi}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```